# How to call ajax in prestashop front end custom module

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have a module  which creates a front end page which displays  winners  of particular draw,I want to add a filter  by year (winning year) when i change the year  it must go by ajax request and change my div

in my display.tpl for the front end  i added below javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
function QuickLook() {
    var year = $("#year").val();
    alert(year);
    $.ajax({
            url:  baseDir+'/modules/addwinners/controllers/front/displaybyajax.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: 'ajax=true&year='+year,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                console.log('success');
                // OTHER SUCCESS COMMAND - CHECK THE RETURN VALUE
                document.getElementById("winnersDiv").innerHTML=response;
            }
    });
    return false;
}

{/literal}
```

but its complaining Fatal error: Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your module controller directly using its full path: `/modules/addwinners/controllers/front/displaybyajax.php` by accessing your controller this way, the dispatcher is not called and Prestashop Core classes are not loaded.

You need to call your controller the Prestashop way:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    function QuickLook() {
        var year = $("#year").val();
        alert(year);
        $.ajax({
            url: baseDir + 'index.php?controller=displaybyajax&redirect=module&module=addwinners',
            type: 'get',
            data: 'ajax=true&year='+year,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                console.log('success');
                // OTHER SUCCESS COMMAND - CHECK THE RETURN VALUE
                document.getElementById("winnersDiv").innerHTML=response;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: I have checked this in my product.js file by calling my custom module, but showing not fount error. Not working any solution on this